# Deleting files from outside filepicker (ink-file-picker)

Tags: filepicker.io

I have a job which goes through and removes un-used files that were originally uploaded via filepicker from my S3 account. Is that a problem? Does file picker sync with S3 and do any sort of cleanup process to remove unused urls automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ink does not automatically delete file URLs that can no longer resolve, so what will happen is that the "www.filepicker.io/api/file/" urls will 404

Comment: Hi Brett, is there a way to delete files uploaded using filepicker with python? I have a job that currently deletes the files using celery